# Set jdk location in ubuntu for glassfish server

Tags: jakarta-ee, ubuntu, glassfish, java-ee-6

While running glassfish server from a windows command prompt, I was getting errors like

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
```

I resolved it by adding one line in the `asenv.bat` file in the config directory of glassfish server folder

```
set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17
```

Now I am getting the same error on Ubuntu and I need to know the syntax that I need to put in the `asenv.bat` file.

My JDK locaion is `\home\szlynas\jdk1.6.0_45`

Comment: Unix path separator isn't `\`.  Try `/` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bat files are for the Windows environment, in Linux you should apply modifications to the *asenv.conf* file.

Comment: AS_JAVA="/home/szlynas/jdk1.6.0_45" (beware the forward slashes)